# bash /bin/grep: Argument list too long (using --file option)

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file containing 33.869 rows and I have to filter 30.067 of them.

With an example:

File: **input.txt** (csv like with 33.869 rows)

```
#00001:A123456.10.101.102,first,row,value2,1
#00002:A123456.10.101.103,second,row,value7,85
(omissis)
#33869:A123456.25.170.180,last,test,value9,0
```

File: **filter.txt** (list of values separated by "\n" with 30.067 rows)

```
A123456.10.101.102
A123456.10.101.103
(omissis)
A123456.24.150.115
```

(expected) Output file: **output.txt** (csv like with 30.067 rows taken from input.txt):

```
#00001:A123456.10.101.102,first,row,value2,1
#00002:A123456.10.101.103,second,row,value7,85
(omissis)
#30067:A123456.24.150.115,whatever,x,y,99
```

The command I'm using is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/grep --file="filter.txt" input.txt > output.txt
```

but error returned is

```
/bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

Am I forced to split "filter.txt" in smaller chunk?

Which is the limit allowed?

I did not find the limit on `man code` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no regular expressions in the input file, you should switch to `grep -F` which can read a significantly larger number of input records.

Failing that, splitting the input file would be hugely more efficient than running 30,000+ iterations of `grep` over the same file.

Here's splitting in chunks of 10,000 lines; adapting to a different factor should be trivial.

```
#!/bin/sh

t=$(mktemp -d -t fgrepsplit.XXXXXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -rf "$t"' EXIT       # Remove temp dir when done
trap 'exit 127' HUP INT TERM  # Remove temp dir if interrupted, too

split -l 10000 "$1" "$t"/pat

for p in "$t"/pat*; do
    grep -F -f "$p" "$2"
done
```

Comment: great! useful! billant! I like it!

Answer (score 2):

From what you write, I wonder whether `grep` is the right tool for the job. With `grep` you would usually try to apply a small set of matching rules, expressed as regular expressions. In your case, you match against a long list of literals.

This seems to be a case of finding the lines that `full_file.txt` and `filtered.txt` have in common. You might want to look at the following tools to achieve this:

- `join` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) gives you the lines that two files have in common. Note that both files have to be sorted. You can use process substitution to achieve this.
- `combine` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/combine) is a more general utility that does not require the input to be sorted. But it may not be available everywhere.

Comment: The issue is a little bit different. let me rename files and be a little bit clear.
I need to find "values.txt" into "input.txt" producing "output.txt".
"values.txt" contains a substring of what has to be searched
"input.txt" contains a list of values (in addition with other information)
"output.txt" must contains all the information available on "input.txt" but filtered by "values.txt".
"join" command works only when fields are identical. And this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

What about iterate on each line of your file ? something like :

```
while IFS= read -r  i ; do
   grep "$i" full_file.txt
done < grep_filter.txt >filtered.txt
```

Comment: If I don't have any other chance, this is the unique approach that I would adopt. It would be much more slower but it satisfied anyway my purpose. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: I added the triplee suggestion to my solution

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F"[:,]" 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($0 in a) {print a[$0]}'  input.txt filter.txt
```